# How do I mark a point in TortoiseSVN for future rollback?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, rollback

I have made some major changes to my code and I before I commit them to my TortoiseSVN, I want to mark the current state of my repository, so that if (probably when!) I need to rollback, I can easily find the spot.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can always rollback the repository to any past revision - that's one of key points of version control - no team member can screw up the repository, effectively any change (other than deleting the repo :) ) can be reverted.

[See this article.](http://sankas.blogspot.com/2008/02/how-to-rollback-svn-repository-to.html)

But any unstable/experimental development should take place in branches and be merged into trunk only when the feature is finalized.

Answer (score 0):

You have a number of options:

- Remember the revision number - You can rollback to it at anytime if you wish
- Create a branch and do the major changes there - Can be merged back to the HEAD then if you wish - This is the best option
- Tag the current revision - Same a option 1 but you don't have to remember anything.

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04.html - For more general information about what you can do in Subversion with branching and tagging.

Comment: Revision comments should be used to describe revisions, tags should represent logical milestones - like release versions or so.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making major change then the best approach is to do them in a branch and merge back to Trunk once you are sure they work.